# String format w/ Proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am playing around w/ string formatting in ruby and I'm doing:

```
"foo%s" % proc {
  "bar"
}.call
```

This works well and all but it's slightly annoying that I have to call `call` to invoke the proc. Is there something like `%s` that invokes the argument given?

*please note that my actual code is not as simple as returning `bar`. This is a GREATLY simplified example (I know I could do something like `"foo#{bar}"`).*

Comment: You could subclass `Proc` and alias its `to_s` to `call` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I considered that but I didn't know if there was a "built-in" way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but what's the point of creating a proc if you're just going to call it straight away? Why not just replace the block with `()` like so

```
"foo%s" % (
  "bar"
)
```

Anyway, to answer your question, there isn't anything exactly like you mentioned. Gsub is the best match I can think of:

```
"foo%s".gsub('%s') { 'bar' }
```

Comment: Good point. If the proc does not come from a different location, it makes no sense to use it at all.

Comment: Did you guys miss the note at the end of the question?